# Embed html contents inside a ajax json reponse in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, escaping

In Rails, from my controller I am sending contents to the browser using

```
my_hash = {text: "<b>This is Bold Content</b>"}
render :json => my_hash
```

my_hash contains strings that have html inside.

Unfortunately, my_hash is escaped and characters like `<` and `>` are converted to `\u003C` and `\u003E` when received by the browser. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You can use render :text => "<b>This is Bold Content</b>" as well

Comment: I made the example very simple. I instead have longer paragraphs with html formatting. I want to display these in the browser using ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems to not be worried about the encoding on the server side and do a unescape on client side browser. Javascript has a `unescape()` function that converts everything back to original text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:-

```
my_hash = {text: "<b>This is Bold Content</b>".html_safe}
render :json => my_hash.to_json
```